# I have two cells that contain delimiter merged values and need to show if any of the values match when the two cells are compared

Tags: excel, string, match, cell, delimiter

Comparing data changes from one year to the other. Person can have 5 IDs one year and two the next. Need to show if any of the IDs still match.

desired result:

[image: desired result]

- J. Doe       (cell1)4455667;443;3344;2345 |(cell2)443234;2345 |(result)One match found
- R. Smith (cell1)1233;3234;45566  45566|(result)One match found
- B. Frank (cell1)667890;989736;98965 |(cell2)989736;98965;998762 |(result)Two matches found
- K. Dole      (cell1)22345;555;345;543444 |(cell2)546444;90555 |(result)No match found

I have a script to find partial string matches but in this case I need to know if exact matches are found so that approach results in too much fall out. If I have to split the delimiter cells into multiple cells and do a match one by one the data and amount of formulas I would need to use would be too huge.

I expect to know if exact value matches are located within the cells that have merged delimited data when compared to another merged delimited cell.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the values are semicolon delimited in each cell. The picture I attached is what I am hoping to obtain as a result.

Comment: Can you make an edit to your post to include the code/formulas you've tried so we can see where you're having trouble?

Comment: I have tried ISNUMBER but that only works if one of the two cells has only one value. If there are multiple values in each cell it returns FALSE all the time: 
 
 
 =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C392|D392))|"found"|IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(D392|C392))|"found"|"NOT"))

Comment: I have also tried a custom partial match script I have that will look for a specified number of consecutive characters and do a match. The problem with that is the IDs can be anywhere from 5 to 13 alpha numeric characters long. So maybe 5 consecutive characters will match in one value of 13 characters but the last digit is off but it still yields a match.

Comment: If anyone has a way to produce the same results as provided by "pnuts" but without splitting out the strings into separate columns I would most appreciate the help! The results are exactly what I needed and I truly appreciate "pnuts" for providing me with this solution. I just have very large quantities of data and was hoping for something cleaner if possible. Basically looking for a way to execute this formula using only two cells and excluding a range as the first matching value =COUNTIF(B2:E2,G2)+COUNTIF(B2:E2,H2)+COUNTIF(B2:E2,I2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your sample data, assumed to be in A1:D5, insert four columns between the two years and after the second, split both years with Text to Columns, Delimited, Semicolon as delimiter and in L2 and copied down to suit:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:E2,G2)+COUNTIF(B2:E2,H2)+COUNTIF(B2:E2,I2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely yields the result I want but the amount of data I have to compare on is huge. Adding this many columns to each field (I have to do this for 8 other field types besides ID) is going to make an already large file even larger. I will have to go this route in the interest of time if I cannot figure something else out. Thank you again!!

Comment: I was able to move forward with my current project using your solution. Thank you so much for the quick and effective response! I very much appreciate your help!!